# Multiply viewcontrollers indise view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I need to create viewcontroller with segmented control and multiply controllers, that will be switched by segmented control. Also I need segmented control to be always on top of the main view. So, I thought about design with scrollview->segmented control->some view, which contains view controllers and switches them by pressing on segmented controll.

Can anyone please share some directions on how to create view and switch view controllers inside that view ?

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers

Comment: It sounds as if you're inventing a `UITabBarController`.

Comment: Yes, kind of. But I need some custom behavior, like pinned to top segmented control

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should use Container Views, you can have multiple container views in one view. This also helps keep your code clean and your storyboard a lot more readable.